# How do I solve this? Can someone give an explanation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, switching, calculation

I don't understand how to calculate the timings for trigger and reset. The answers are 394.1ms & 11.3s respectively. But I don't know the explanation behind it.
[image: Question & Circuit Diagram]

[image: Circuit Diagram Enlarged]

Comment: What about if you remove the mosfets and treat the diodes as short circuits? Does that help you begin the analysis?

Comment: Take the tour in the bottom left.  There is a minimum standard for homework questions so once you get started you'll have to show some work.